# Enemy Taking Multiple Damage - Swift, Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm in the process of making a space invaders style game, and would like to make it so that an enemy must be hit three times before exploding.

The tutorial I am using only shows how to make enemies explode after only one hit. It uses a function called `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0kcw6eryJs&t=617s

Now, this function, from my understanding, evaluates each instance of contact, assigns two bodies two distinct roles, and then decides what to do with each body. I assume to have an enemy take three hits, a variable containing their remaining health would be used. Then, with each instance of contact, the variable would decrease by one, until if it is zero, the enemy is removed.

However, there is a deep problem in this. Since`didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` evaluates only one instance of contact, it has no knowledge of other previous instances of contact. Essentially, when an enemy gets hit, there is no way to know if the enemy was hit before, has not been hit at all, or has been hit too many times. If there was only one enemy, then I could use one variable to keep track of its health. This is not the case, though, as there are multiple enemies on screen at once, and every time contact is made, there is no way to know if the previous hit was on this enemy, or another enemy.

If there is one enemy on screen, it is simple because every time contact is made it would have to be that one enemy. But if there are multiple entities on screen, then there is no way to know which enemy a contact applies to.

I believe this would require some sort of identification for each instance of an enemy, though I an unsure of how to do this. For those of you reading, I have many thanks for dropping in, and I am very grateful if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to keep separate dictionaries to track states of a sprite

Every SKNode has `userData`, and you can track an enemies life with it

Example:

```
let invader = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"invader")
invader.userData = ["health":3]

...


func didBeginContact(...)
{
...
  //when a contact happens
    contact.body_.node.userData["health"] -= 1
...
}
```

Now keep in mind, 1 bullet can hit 1 enemy two times.  You do not want to trigger 2 losses of life here,  so you are going to need to have a temporary variable (which you can also save in userData) that lets you know if a particular bullet has already made contact with an invader.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I was wondering, in `func didBeginContact` what is the exact formatting for deducting the variable health? When you refer to `body_`, do you mean bodyA or bodyB, or should I test for both, as it says SKPhysicsContact has no member "body." in addition, when trying to deduct one, it gives the error `Binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Int'`. This is confusing, as it seems like type `Int` can be operated on. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Body_ is whatever body your invader is. The category will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, you somehow need to track your enemies and their health on your own. There are probably a bunch of ways to do it but here is one way of achieving what your aiming for:

Use a dictionary of enemies with their health. Every enemy will be given an id of some sort to identify them. The health could be represented as an Int. This dictionary can also be used to easily tell how many enemies are still around.

```
var enemyHealth = [String:Int]()
```

Nodes have a name property that you can set any string value to. This is how you'll be able to identify your nodes. When creating an enemy, you'll create an id (for instance generating a random number), set the name of the node as the id and add the enemy to the `enemyHealth` dictionary with a default health value.

```
let enemyNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize.zero)
let enemyId = "\(arc4random())"
enemyNode.name = enemyId
enemyHealth[enemyId] = 10
...
```

In `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` you can access the involved nodes in the collision using the contact parameter of the function (`contact.bodyA.node` or `contact.bodyB.node`). By comparing the names of the nodes with the keys in `enemyHealth`, you can figure out which collision body was the enemy and what health it has.

```
let enemy:SKSpriteNode

if enemyHealth.keys.contains(contact.bodyA.node?.name ?? "") {
    enemy = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode

} else if enemyHealth.keys.contains(contact.bodyB.node?.name ?? "") {
    enemy = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
} else {
    return  //none of the collision partners are an enemy
}

let health = enemyHealth[enemy.name!]!
...
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the enemy. When the enemy is killed/removed then also remove it from the `enemyHealth` dictionary.